# Pandas new column from groupby averages

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
...                    'b':[10,20,20,10,20,20],
...                    'result':[100,200,300,400,500,600]})
... 
>>> df
   a   b  result
0  1  10     100
1  1  20     200
2  1  20     300
3  2  10     400
4  2  20     500
5  2  20     600
```

and want to create a new column that is the average result for the corresponding values for 'a' and 'b'. I can get those values with a groupby:

```
>>> df.groupby(['a','b'])['result'].mean()
a  b 
1  10    100
   20    250
2  10    400
   20    550
Name: result, dtype: int64
```

but can not figure out how to turn that into a new column in the original DataFrame. The final result should look like this,

```
>>> df
   a   b  result  avg_result
0  1  10     100         100
1  1  20     200         250
2  1  20     300         250
3  2  10     400         400
4  2  20     500         550
5  2  20     600         550
```

I could do this by looping through the combinations of 'a' and 'b' but that would get really slow and unwieldy for larger sets of data. There is probably a much simpler and faster way to go.

Comment: I want to stress how well this question is written and how its minimal example code makes it greatly useful for future readers.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation):

```
df['avg_result'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['result'].transform('mean')
```

This generates a correctly indexed column of the groupby values for you:

```
   a   b  result  avg_result
0  1  10     100         100
1  1  20     200         250
2  1  20     300         250
3  2  10     400         400
4  2  20     500         550
5  2  20     600         550
```

Comment: This needs to be re-looked now since there are some updates and the above is returning error - `TypeError: 'GroupedData' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @MithunTheertha: the code works fine for me on version 1.5.3. Are you running this under pyspark instead? pandas does not have a `GroupedData` object, but pyspark does.

Comment: Yes I agree, later I figured out this, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the previous answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/33445035/6504287) is pandas based, I'm adding the pyspark based solution as in below:
So it is better to go with the `Window` function as in the below code snippet example:

```
    windowSpecAgg  = Window.partitionBy('a', 'b')
    ext_data_df.withColumn('avg_result', avg('result').over(windowSpecAgg)).show()
```

The above code is with respect to the example took in the previously provided solution(https://stackoverflow.com/a/33445035/6504287).

Answer (score 0):

you need to reset the index, like:

```
df.reset_index()
```

the output should be like you want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).