# pandas personalized groupby data arithmetic manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataframe:

```
    id_1 id_2  cost  id_3 other
0      1    a    30    10     a
1      1    a    30    20     f
2      1    a    30    30     h
3      1    b    60    40     b
4      1    b    60    50     m
5      2    a    10    60     u
6      2    a    10    70     l
7      2    b     8    80     u
8      3    c    15    90     y
9      3    c    15   100     l
10     4    d     8   110     m
11     5    e     5   120     v
```

I want a `groupby(['id_1', 'id_2'])`, but

- Dividing the `cost` number, which is the same in each line of same group, between each of these lines (for example, dividing `30/3=10` between the three `a` values).

I would expect something like this:

```
    id_1 id_2   cost  id_3 other
0      1    a     10    10     a
1      1    a     10    20     f
2      1    a     10    30     h
3      1    b     30    40     b
4      1    b     30    50     m
5      2    a      5    60     u
6      2    a      5    70     l
7      2    b      8    80     u
8      3    c    7.5    90     y
9      3    c    7.5   100     l
10     4    d      8   110     m
11     5    e      5   120     v
```

It is a similar question to 
[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445009/pandas-new-column-from-groupby-averages). But now I want more flexibility in manipulating data inside a group of rows.

How can I proceed?

Thaks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do `transform`

```
df.cost/=df.groupby(['id_1','id_2']).cost.transform('count')
df
    id_1 id_2  cost  id_3 other
0      1    a  10.0    10     a
1      1    a  10.0    20     f
2      1    a  10.0    30     h
3      1    b  30.0    40     b
4      1    b  30.0    50     m
5      2    a   5.0    60     u
6      2    a   5.0    70     l
7      2    b   8.0    80     u
8      3    c   7.5    90     y
9      3    c   7.5   100     l
10     4    d   8.0   110     m
11     5    e   5.0   120     v
```